# Applying size change to an object for all keyframes

Tags: grease-pencil, timeline

I want to make the monkey (highlighted) larger on the x-z plane for all the keyframes, but I can only apply the scale to one key frame and not the rest. I get into Edit mode, type `S` to scale, and then check the other keyframes and find that only the immediate keyframe that I edited has been changed.

How do I change the size of the monkey for all keyframes across the timeline?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the scale to delta by selecting the object, scaling it and press ctrl + a (for mac: cmd + a) -> scale to delta. You can also access delta scale via the properties panel: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jun7a.jpg

This will offset the scale of the object in addition to the base scale, and will ignore keyframes used to animate other parameters while keeping the proportional scaling between keyframe.

Comment: good answer, simply add the keyboard command or a screenshot of the menu where you can find the scale to delta option

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Oops sorry I realise that this is for grease pencil, not sure it will work for GS.

You can do it with the *Graph Editor*: Open it, select the X and Z *Scale* tracks, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to mask the other tracks:

[image]

Select the F curves and move them on the Y axis of the *Graph Editor*:

[image]